# Align multiple headings above multiple iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have six `iframe`s in total and would like to add three headings above them.

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>Title xxx</title>
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
    
    <meta name="keywords" content="xxxx" />
    <meta name="description" name="description" content="xxxx" />
    
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="public" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public" />
    
    <meta http-equiv="identifier-url" name="Identifier-URL" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="revisit-after" name="Revisit-after" content="7 days" />
    <meta http-equiv="robots" name="Robots" content="all" />
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX|FOLLOW" />
    
    <meta name="Author" content="xxx xxx, xxx Team" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <section id="a_logo">
            <img src="images/a_logo.png">
        </section>
        <section id="b_logo">
            <img src="images/b_logo.png">
        </section>
        <!-- content -->
        <section id="content">
            <h1>Linux UF Packages</h1>
                <a href="packages/linux/xxx_PROD_nonDMZ.tgz">xxx Linux non DMZ PROD (x64)</a></br>
                <a href="packages/linux/xxx_PROD_DMZ.tgz">xxx Linux DMZ PROD (x64)</a></br>
                <a href="packages/linux/xxx_AB_nonDMZ.tgz">xxx Linux non DMZ AB (x64)</a></br>
                <a href="packages/linux/xxx_AB_DMZ.tgz">xxx Linux DMZ AB (x64)</a></br>
                <a href="packages/linux/xxx_EW_nonDMZ.tgz">xxx Linux non DMZ EW (x64)</a></br>
                <a href="packages/linux/xxx_EW_DMZ.tgz">xxx Linux DMZ EW (x64)</a></br>
                <a href="packages/linux/xxx.docx">Installation Guide </a>
            <h1>Windows UF Packages</h1>
                <a href="packages/windows/xxx_x64.zip">xxx Windows PROD, AB, EW (x64)</a></br>
                <a href="packages/windows/xxx.docx">Installation Guide for Windows</a>
        </section>
        <section id="stats">
        <div>
            <h2>header</h2>
            <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
            <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>header2</h2>
            <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
            <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>header3</h2>
            <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
            <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
        </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>Created and managed by <a href="mailto:xxx&subject=xxx">xxx Team</a> 2021 | Last update: 2021-12-28</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 50px;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #434343;
  background: #fff;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#a_logo {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
#b_logo {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 600px;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#content {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 25px 50px 25px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-image: url("../images/");
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#content h1 {
  clear: both;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#content a {
  color: #6e6e6e;
}
#content a:hover {
  color: #b18904;
}
#content a:visited {
  color: #848484;
}

#stats iframe {
  display: inline-block;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0 50px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
}
footer p a {
  color: #6e6e6e;
}
footer p a:hover {
  color: #b18904;
}
footer p a:visited {
  color: #848484;
}
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
header          header2        header3
iframe(prod1)   iframe(uat1)   iframe(dev1)
iframe(prod2)   iframe(uat2)   iframe(dev2)
```

I already tried several ways but it either breaks the vertical structure of the iframes or the headings are not in the right position.

Comment: The last set of `<iframe>`s and the 3 `<header>`s aren't posted.

Comment: I haven't added the headings because I wasn't successful. I have 6 iframes in total which are shown in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```css
#stats {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#stats iframe {
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<section id="stats">
  <div>
    <h2>header</h2>
    <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
    <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>header2</h2>
    <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
    <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>header3</h2>
    <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
    <iframe height="160" width="480" frameborder="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: justify-content: center; can be removed if you don't want them spread across the page

Comment: I implemented your recommendations and the iframes are now vertical aligned and the first heading is on the top and the center of the page.

Comment: Do you have a code sample of what you tried to do?  When you run the code snippet above it works so I'm thinking you have CSS overriding something somewhere.

Comment: I added the whole html file in my initial posting.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you want is a table -- so you can use:

- `<table>`     or `display: table`
- `<thead>`     or `display: table-header-group`
- `<tbody>`     or `display: table-row-group`
- `<tr>`           or `display: table-row`
- `<th>`,`<td>` or `display: table-cell`

The example below uses the [`display` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#internal)

```css
#stats {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.head {
  display: table-header-group
}

.body {
  display: table-row-group
}

.row {
  display: table-row
}

h2,
.row div {
  display: table-cell
}

iframe {
  border: 0
}

.r1 iframe {
  height: 160px;
  width: 480px;
}

.r2 iframe {
  height: 340px;
  width: 480px;
}

.A {
  outline: 3px dashed tomato;
}

.B {
  outline: 3px dashed lime;
}

.C {
  outline: 3px dashed cyan;
}

.D {
  outline: 3px dashed violet;
}

.E {
  outline: 3px dashed goldenrod;
}

.F {
  outline: 3px dashed navy;
}
```

```html
<section id="stats">
  <header class='head'>
    <h2>Header1</h2>
    <h2>Header2</h2>
    <h2>Header3</h2>
  </header>
  <section class='body'>
    <div class='row r1'>
      <div>
        <iframe class='A' src="about:blank"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div>
        <iframe class='B' src="about:blank"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div>
        <iframe class='C' src="about:blank"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row r2'>
      <div>
        <iframe class='D' src="about:blank"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div>
        <iframe class='E' src="about:blank"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div>
        <iframe class='F' src="about:blank"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the three headings are centralized at the top of the page and the iframes are just vertical ordered.

Comment: Do mean the text is centered? That's easily remedied ...OK it's fixed.

Comment: Yes, the text ist centered and at the top of the page and the iframes are  in a vertical order.